# Recordset empty issue

Tags: excel, vba, postgresql

I have issue with filling up recordset.

I stored this query into txt file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "temp_invoice_id_amount_1";
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "temp_invoice_id_amount_1" AS
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() "RN",
    c."ID" "CaseID",
    p."ID" "PackageID",
    trim(concat(d."LastName", ' ', d."FirstName")) "FullName",
    c."ContragentCaseID",
    i."ID" "InvoiceID",
    i."AccountNum",
    i."FromDate" "InvoiceFromDate",
    i."ToDate" "InvoiceToDate",
    i."InvoiceCurrency",
    (coalesce(sum(td."Amount" * er."Value"), 0) * (-1)):: NUMERIC(12,2) "NumActualInvoiceAmount",
    trim(replace(to_char((coalesce(sum(td."Amount" * er."Value"), 0) * (-1)):: NUMERIC(12,2), '99999990D00'),'.',',')) "ActualInvoiceAmount"
FROM "Package" p
JOIN "Case" c ON p."ID" = c."PackageID"
JOIN "Debtor" d ON d."ID" = c."DebtorID"
JOIN "Invoice" i ON c."ID" = i."CaseID" AND i."IsDeleted" = 0
LEFT JOIN "Transaction" t ON i."ID" = t."InvoiceID" AND t."IsDeleted" = 0 AND t."IsPayment" = 0
LEFT JOIN "TransactionDetails" td ON t."ID" = td."TransactionID"
LEFT JOIN "ExchangeRate" er ON
    --t."PaymentDate" BETWEEN er."FromDate" AND er."ToDate" AND
    er."SourceCurrency" = t."Currency" AND
    er."DestinationCurrency" = i."InvoiceCurrency"
WHERE p."ID" in ($package)
AND i."AccountNum" not like 'OP%'
AND p."Inserted" + interval '1 minute' > i."Inserted"
group by c."ID", trim(concat(d."LastName", ' ', d."FirstName")), c."ContragentCaseID", i."FromDate", i."ToDate",
         i."InvoiceCurrency", i."ID", p."ID";

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "idx_temp_invoice_id_amount_1" ON temp_invoice_id_amount_1("InvoiceID");

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "temp_case_id_amount_1";
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "temp_case_id_amount_1" AS
SELECT t1."CaseID",
       trim(replace(to_char((coalesce(sum(t1."NumActualInvoiceAmount" * er_eur."Value"), 0)):: NUMERIC(12,2), '99999990D00'),'.',',')) "ActualCaseAmount_EUR",
       trim(replace(to_char((coalesce(sum(t1."NumActualInvoiceAmount"), 0)):: NUMERIC(12,2), '99999990D00'),'.',',')) "ActualCaseAmount_HRK"
FROM temp_invoice_id_amount_1 t1
LEFT JOIN "ExchangeRate" er_eur ON
    current_date BETWEEN er_eur."FromDate" AND er_eur."ToDate" AND
    er_eur."SourceCurrency" = t1."InvoiceCurrency" AND
    er_eur."DestinationCurrency" = 'EUR'
LEFT JOIN "ExchangeRate" er_hrk ON
    current_date BETWEEN er_hrk."FromDate" AND er_hrk."ToDate" AND
    er_hrk."SourceCurrency" = t1."InvoiceCurrency" AND
    er_hrk."DestinationCurrency" = 'HRK'
GROUP BY t1."CaseID";

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "idx_temp_case_id_amount_1" ON temp_case_id_amount_1("CaseID");

SELECT ti1."RN",
       ti1."CaseID",
       --ti1."PackageID",
       ti1."FullName",
       'ZIPPY',
       'CITTY',
       'STREETY',
       ti1."ContragentCaseID",
       --ti1."InvoiceID",
      -- ti1."AccountNum",
       ti1."InvoiceFromDate",
       ti1."InvoiceToDate",
       ti1."InvoiceCurrency",
       ti1."ActualInvoiceAmount",
       '0',
       --tc1."ActualCaseAmount_EUR",
       tc1."ActualCaseAmount_HRK",
       '0'
FROM temp_invoice_id_amount_1 ti1
JOIN "temp_case_id_amount_1" tc1 ON ti1."CaseID" = tc1."CaseID";
```

Then i used this part to read from txt file:

```
Dim strSQL2 As String
fileSpec = "\\192.168.0.7\...\Reports\confirmation.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)
strSQL2 = objTS.ReadAll
strSQL2 = Replace(strSQL2, "$package", package)
objTS.Close
```

And this part for executing the query:

```
cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
cmd.CommandText = strSQL

cmd2.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
cmd2.ActiveConnection = Conn
cmd2.CommandText = strSQL2

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = cmd.Execute

Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = cmd2.Execute
```

But for some reason recordset **rs2** is totally empty while **rs1** is normally filled with data.
Does anyone knows what could be reason why recordset **rs2** is empty?

Comment: You probably need to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` since the first part of your query doesn't return data.

Comment: Can you tell me where should i put it, i tried to put it before DROP TABLE part (getting error), then i tried before first select (syntax error at or near "SET")?

Comment: It should go right at the start as far as I know.

Comment: unfortunately its not working :/ getting syntax error at or near "ON";

Comment: Ah, I missed your postgresql tag - I don't think it has `NOCOUNT`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I suspect the issue is you are executing everything at once.  It's likely doing everything but not returning the results the way you expect.

I think what you may want to do is execute each code block in sequence rather than all at once.

Something like this:

```
Dim rs2 as ADODB.Recordset

For Each codeBlock In Split(strSQL2, ";")
  cmd2.CommandText = codeBlock
  rs2 = cmd2.Execute
Next codeBlock
```

You can also put a breakpoint on each "execute" to check the results at each step.

You'll probably also need to omit the final semicolon so it doesn't try to execute blank (or otherwise handle that the command text has to contain some non-whitespace).

Out of curiosity, why the temp tables?  Why not simply run the query?  Have you considered functions/views?

Comment: Great thinking, thank you for that i will try it for sure.
Ahh.. temp tables, because we dont have full access to DB and providers told us to
use this method of extracting data because structure of that DB doesnt like "complex" queries
with sub-queries, so they recommended to write all sub-queries as normal query and join all tables together

Comment: Consider Common Table Expressions (CTE) also then -- no special permissions required.  If you are on Pg 12 or higher you can also materialize the CTE which will essentially function like an inline temp table.  `with cte as (your query) select * from cte`.  So you can make temp_case_id_amount_1 a CTE...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find exact solution but workaround solution.

I splitted my query into 2 separate txt files.

First file contains part where i am dropping and creating temp tables,

and second file contains only this:

```
SELECT ti1."RN",
   ti1."CaseID",
   --ti1."PackageID",
   ti1."FullName",
   'ZIPPY',
   'CITTY',
   'STREETY',
   ti1."ContragentCaseID",
   --ti1."InvoiceID",
  -- ti1."AccountNum",
   ti1."InvoiceFromDate",
   ti1."InvoiceToDate",
   ti1."InvoiceCurrency",
   ti1."ActualInvoiceAmount",
   '0',
   --tc1."ActualCaseAmount_EUR",
   tc1."ActualCaseAmount_HRK",
   '0'
FROM temp_invoice_id_amount_1 ti1
JOIN "temp_case_id_amount_1" tc1 ON ti1."CaseID" = tc1."CaseID";
```

Then i executed these 2 files separately.